# Apple Metal iOS why does GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt rock back and forth

Tags: ios, swift, metal, glkit, metalkit

I am developing a 3D scene on iOS 16.1 with Xcode 14.3. I have a rectangular plane orbiting the origin at an incline and I want to use GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt to cause the plane to always face the origin.

I am using the code below. The plane does 'face' the origin when it rotates, however I am also seeing this undesired 'rocking' ( yaw ) back and forth. Please see the attached video to understand how it looks.

Why does it do this rocking? How can I get rid of the rocking but still have the plane orbit the origin and always face it? Thank you.

[image]

Code:

```
// Get the lookat scene origin matrix for the rectangle
var lookAtSceneOriginGLKMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity
var lookAtSceneOriginInverse = GLKMatrix4Identity
var rectangleModelMatrix = float4x4()
var lookAtSceneOriginMat = float4x4()

lookAtSceneOriginGLKMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(lookAtSceneOriginGLKMatrix, GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(self.currentSatX * self.appDelegate.getCurrentRectangle().getRenderHeight(), self.currentSatY * self.appDelegate.getCurrentRectangle().getRenderHeight(), self.currentSatZ * self.appDelegate.getCurrentRectangle().getRenderHeight(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
var isInvertible = true
lookAtSceneOriginInverse = GLKMatrix4Invert(lookAtSceneOriginGLKMatrix, &isInvertible)
lookAtSceneOriginMat = float4x4(convertToFloat4x4FromGLKMatrix: lookAtSceneOriginInverse)
rectangleModelMatrix = accumulatedRotationMatrix * lookAtSceneOriginMat * float4x4(scaleBy: 0.35)

// Draw the rectangular plane
scene.rectanglePlane?.draw(
    encoder: commandEncoder, modelMatrix: rectangleModelMatrix,
    projectionMatrix: projectionMatrix * viewMatrix
)
```

Comment: If I had to guess, you are changing look at and up vector at the same time, which will lead to this sort of precession. Up vector has to stay up, otherwise you kinda get into situation where a side to side motion precesses the up vector as well, which causes this weird lazy 8 motion,

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So in my call to GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt, the last 6 arguments are 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0. I believe this means that the up vector does not change each draw call. Was that the up vector you were referring to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a Comment your up vector always pointing to the direction of y axis. It should be perpendicular to the direction vector.

```
let x = self.currentSatX * self.appDelegate.getCurrentRectangle().getRenderHeight()
let y = self.currentSaty * self.appDelegate.getCurrentRectangle().getRenderHeight()
let z = self.currentSatZ * self.appDelegate.getCurrentRectangle().getRenderHeight()

let direction = GLKVector3Make(x, y, z) //vector from planes postion to origin

let yAx = GLKVector3Make(0, 1, 0) // y axis

let side = GLKVector3CrossProduct(direction, yAx) //perpendicular vector to direction

let up = GLKVector3CrossProduct(side, direction) //perpendicular vector to side
let normalizedUp = GLKVector3Normalize(up)

lookAtSceneOriginGLKMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(lookAtSceneOriginGLKMatrix, GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(x, y, z, 0, 0, 0, normalizedUp.x, normalizedUp.y, normalizedUp.z))
```